# How to get the Grey Loading to show when loading Lightning from Visualforce like salesforce does

Tags: visualforce, lightning

How can you get the grey loading image to appear when using visualforce to display a Lightning App/Component

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSS is missing something when displayed in pure lightning as the box is squished vertically but in VF from classic it looks as expected. (Todo: figure out the CSS that works for both)

using the below CSS and Content (Lightning CreateComponent included as example only and is not needed to show the loading box)

```
<apex:includeLightning/>

<style>

    #auraLoadingBox.auraMsgBox {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 120px auto 0;
        background-color: #708090;
        z-index: 1002;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 20px 40px rgba(0,0,0,.8),inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3);
        overflow: hidden
    }

    #auraLoadingBox.auraMsgBox h2 {
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        overflow: hidden
    }

    #auraLoadingBox.auraLoadingBox {
        text-align: center;
        width: 200px;
        line-height: 80px
    }
</style>
<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:AppName", function () {
        $Lightning.createComponent(
                "c:ComponentName",
                {},
                "selector-content",
                function (cmp) {
                    var loadingDivElt = document.getElementById("auraLoadingBox");
                    loadingDivElt.style.display = 'none';
                    //Used for navigate event from the component. Not needed for this example
                    $A.eventService.addHandler({
                        event: 'force:navigateToURL',
                        handler: function (event) {
                            if (typeof sforce != 'undefined' && sforce.one) {
                                // VF page in S1 or Lightning Exp
                                // VF page in Classic
                                sforce.one.navigateToURL('/');
                            } else {
                                window.parent.location.href = '/';
                            }

                        }
                    });
                });
    });

</script>

<div id="auraLoadingBox" class="auraMsgBox auraLoadingBox">
    <h2>Loading</h2>
</div>
<div id="selector-content">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, this code displays the 6 dot SLDS blue [Spinner](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/spinners/) (a familiar sight to anyone using Lightning Experience) in the Visualforce page before the Lightning app/component starts up:

```
<apex:page>

<apex:slds/>
<div id="spinner" class="slds-spinner_container">
    <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner--medium slds-spinner--brand">
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
        <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
        <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<apex:includeLightning />
<div id="lightning" />
<script>
$Lightning.use('c:myApp', function() {
    $Lightning.createComponent(
            'c:myComponent',
            {id: '{! $CurrentPage.parameters.id }'},
            "lightning",
            function() {document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = 'none';}
    );
});
</script>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: I use that as well. In fact I have now switched to if in lightning native I use the spinner but if in classic I use my above loading css. My above loading CSS does not look the greatest in native lightning... Still trying to bring the gap between VF closing the loading and the lightning component actually rendering. heavy components still have white screen for a bit......But that is a design issue in the component I believe...

Comment: This will defiantly help others looking to use either variation

Comment: @Eric Take your point about the two contexts; I just took the easy route given there is now `apex:slds`.